# Laravel: Foreign id does not have default value

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I run this request `POST 0.0.0.0:80/api/clients/1/details?preferred_day=wednesday&preferred_time=08:00:00&goals=get better!` in Postman, I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `client_details` (`preferred_day`, `preferred_time`, `goals`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (wednesday, 08:00:00, get better!, 2022-05-01 14:31:51, 2022-05-01 14:31:51))
```

From my understanding, the `ClientDetail` model should be defined as below. Notice the relationship and the fact that `client_id` is fillable.

```
class ClientDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = ['client_id','preferred_day','preferred_time','goals'];

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class,'client_id');
    }
}
```

I have written the Client model as below. Notice that I have the inverse relationship defined as per the docs.

```
class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name','email','phone_number','address','unit','postal_code','province','city','country'];

    public function detail() {
        return $this->hasOne(ClientDetail::class);
    }

    public function concerns() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Concern::class);
    }
}
```

Finally the migration is defined as below:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('client_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained();
      $table->string('preferred_day')->default('wednesday');
      $table->time('preferred_time')->useCurrent();
      $table->longText('goals');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is functioning as expected because when I look at DB, I see the following (notice how the foreign key references `client.id`):
[image]

I have run dd on the request and I get the result below.
[image]

The only thing I can see is that the binding of routes is not working properly. I have included them below. Any assistance troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT - Added store function as requested**

**ClientDetailController.php**

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'preferred_day' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in('wednesday','friday'),
            ],
            'preferred_time' => 'required|date_format:h:i:s',
            'goals' => 'required|min:10',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        $validated = $validator->validated();

        $detail = ClientDetail::create($validated);
        return new ClientDetailResource($detail);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure "foreign id" is autoload? I think, you must set "client_id" value in INSERT action.

Comment: @UioSun can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: INSERT INTO `client_details` (`client_id`, `preferred_day`... ← set "client_id" value (and my english so weak, hah, sorry about it.)

Comment: @UioSun no problem, I understand what you mean now. From my understanding, I shouldn't need to pass it as a value due to the fact that it should be bound to route?

Comment: You should share the piece of code where you are actually creating ClientDetails. The error is given because you do not pass `client_id` when creating.

Comment: DONT use $guarded and $fillable at the same time.  Remove one of them.

Comment: Where is your controller method?

Comment: If you do not share the controller responsible of the error, we cannot know what you are doing to trigger that error...

Comment: can you show the code that is actually trying to do the insert?

Comment: Hello all, I have added the store function as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

`$detail = ClientDetail::create($validated);`

Explanation:
You are creating Client Details without a Client themselves, in other words you must populate `client_id` with a proper value:
You have to options: just before the wrong line mentioned above:

1. NOT RECOMMENDED, hard code the client_id just so you can test this. by doing this line `$validated['client_id'] = 1` where 1 is example.
2. Do it properly by adding getting a client then create/store their details.

```php
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Client $client, Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'preferred_day' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in('wednesday','friday'),
            ],
            'preferred_time' => 'required|date_format:h:i:s',
            'goals' => 'required|min:10',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        $validated = $validator->validated();

        // $client var is type-hinted in the function signature above 
        $client->detail()->create($validated);
        $detail = ClientDetail::create();
        return new ClientDetailResource($detail);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Mo that worked. Just one two adjustments I had to make. I had to drop that $detail = ClientDetail::create(), and then update $client->detail()->create($validated) to $detail = $client->detail()->create($validated);